# TypeError: done() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

In my following program I basicly want to create a edit field which, after I double click it, transforms into a label with the text I wrote in the edit field. Here is my code:

GUI.py:

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
import Classes
root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Schelling-Cup Alpha 1.0")
root.config(background = "#FFFFFF")

#VARIABLEN LADEN

playerlist = []

#BILDER WERDEN GELADEN

hintergrund = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\Jakub Pietraszko\\Desktop\\MarioKartProject\\Hintergrund2.png")
fotobutton1 = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\Jakub Pietraszko\\Desktop\\MarioKartProject\\Button_8Spieler_.png")
fotobutton2 = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\Jakub Pietraszko\\Desktop\\MarioKartProject\\Button_16Spieler_.png")


#FIRSTFRAME EDITED
firstFrame = Frame(root, width=400, height = 400)
firstFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 3, pady = 3)
x = Label(firstFrame, image = hintergrund)
x.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
def callback1():
    """Die Funktion für 8 Spieler, welche dann den entsprechenden Frame lädt."""
    Classes.EditToLabel(400, 400, firstFrame)
    pass
def callback2():
    """Die Funktion für 16 Spieler, welche dann den entsprechenden Frame lädt."""
    pass
B1 = Button(firstFrame, text = "Button1", bg = "#FFFFFF", width = 700, command = callback1)
B1.config(image = fotobutton1)
B1.place(x = 290, y = 250)
B2 = Button(firstFrame, text = "Button2", bg ="#FFFFFF", width = 700, command = callback2)
B2.config(image = fotobutton2)
B2.place(x = 290, y = 450)

#SECOUNDFRAME EDITED

secoundFrame = Frame(root, width = 400, height = 400)


root.mainloop() #GUI wird upgedated. Danach keine Elemente setzen
```

And here is my secound file, Classes.py:

```
from tkinter import *
import sys

x = 100
y = 100

class EditToLabel():
    def __init__(self, x_Koordinate, y_Koordinate, whichFrame):
        self.x_Koordinate = x_Koordinate
        self.y_Koordinate = y_Koordinate
        self.whichFrame = whichFrame

        global neuesEntry
        neuesEntry = Entry(whichFrame, width = 40)
        neuesEntry.place(x = x_Koordinate, y = y_Koordinate)

        neuesEntry.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.done)
    def done(self):
        Eintrag = neuesEntry.get()
        neuesEntry.destroy()
        neuesLabel = Label(self.whichFrame, text = Eintrag, x = self.x_Koordinate, y = self.y_Koordinate)
```

Now the problem is, that I get and error and dont know exactly what to do. Following error message I get now:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:...\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line
>   1705, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args) TypeError: done() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Does anybody know what I make wrong and could give me an example how to make it better and improve it?

Comment: `self.done`, the bound method, doesn't take any arguments. The callback is expected to take one.

Comment: Does it need to accept an argument? I mean I dont have anything I could hand over to the menthod. What do you mean with the "callback"?

Comment: **EXACT** duplicate of [attribute-error-with-event-object-and-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54671965/attribute-error-with-event-object-and-classes)

Comment: `self.done()` will be called with 2 arguments, the instance reference and the event object, because it is used as callback function of `bind()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When binding a method in Tkinter, the app sends information about the event as and argument to the function even if you dont use it.

Try:

```
def done(self, event = None):
    ...
```

Setting "event" as a default parametrer helps when you need to use `self.done()` 
through other methods besides `.bind()`.

Comment: This worked very well, and also thx for the explanation. I really apriciate it!